# C# - How to drawLine on top of the chart or another control

Tags: c#

I want to draw a line between 2 points on a chart but I cannot use ChartStyle.Line so I tried to use Graphics.DrawLine.

My problem is that I cant draw on top of the chart.  How can I solve this?

```
        PointF pontoantigo = new PointF();

            if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
            {
                 pontoantigo = new PointF((int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue, (int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0]);
            }


            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();

            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(posicao_atual_master.X, posicao_atual_master.Y);
            PointF pontoatual = new PointF((int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue, (int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0]);

            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            Graphics g = chart1.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawLine(p, pontoantigo, pontoatual);
```

EDIT:

FUNCTION THAT updates the value of the old and new points:

```
  pontoantigo = new PointF();
            if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 0)
            {
                pontoantigo = new PointF((int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue, (int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0]);
            }


            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();

            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(posicao_atual_master.X, posicao_atual_master.Y);
            pontoatual = new PointF((int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue, (int)chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0]);
```

POSTPAINT:

```
   private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
    {

        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
        Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(p, pontoantigo, pontoatual);

    }
```

STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: Well, I have posted [many solutions here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+Chart++prepaint) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+Chart++postpaint) for drawing onto a Chart. - Also: __Never__ use `control.CreateGraphics`! In the `PrePaint` or the `PostPaint` event of a control, using the `e.ChartGraphics.Graphics` parameter.. - Also dispose of the pen and other gdi object you create. And understand about coordinate system in a chart! (Hint: There are __3__ of them!!)

Comment: C# is used for many, many UI technologies. In the future, please include a tag indicating the UI technology you're using.

Comment: Nvm It's called everytime. I will update my code. It's not working atm.

Comment: @TaW it's drawing but the coordinates are wrong. Can you tell me which coordinates exist?

Comment: I want the XY coordinates of the graph not the location.

Comment: Read the post I showed you and you will get what you want. the coordinates are delivered by AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition and AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to convert `DataPoints` to drawing `Points`:

```
Point PointFromDataPoint(Chart chart, ChartArea ca, DataPoint pt)
{
    Axis ax = chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    int x = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(pt.XValue);                    
    int y = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(pt.YValues[0]);
    return new Point(x, y);
}
```

If you have set the two `DataPoints` (!!) `pontoantigo` and `pontoatual` you can write the `PrePaint` event:

```
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Green, 2f))
        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(pen,
            PointFromDataPoint(chart1, chart1.ChartAreas[0], pontoantigo),
            PointFromDataPoint(chart1, chart1.ChartAreas[0], pontoatual));
}
```

Here is the result of combining [this little post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506942/is-there-a-bug-of-system-windows-forms-datavisualization-charting-chart-when-se/40507400#40507400) and setting the two `DataPoints` like this:

```
 DataPoint pontoantigo = chart1.Series[0].Points.First();
 DataPoint pontoatual  = chart1.Series[0].Points.Last();
```

[image]